# Navigation menu disappears after moving from small to full screen

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I have created a mobile responsive menu where I have replaced the icon and show/hide the menu.

**First** The main navigation menu is doing fine and I resize the screen and move to the mobile version. 
**Then** I have clicked the hamburger menu, it worked fine. 
**When** I make the window size larger again, the main navigation menu is not showing up.
**So the issue is**, my main navigation menu disappears when I move from 767px size to full screen.
I have used ionic icons where **ion-navicon-round** is hamburger menu and **ion-close-round** is the large x icon.

Here is situation described with the images.
First: In the full screen
[image: First: In the full screen]

This is the responsive menu.
[image: This is the responsive menu]

Navigation menu disappeared.
[image: Navigation menu disappeared]

This is my HTML Code for the navigation menu.

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
    <li><a href="#features">Food delivery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#works">How it works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cities">Our cities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#plans">Sign up</a></li>
 </ul>

<a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
```

Here is the Jquery code that I have used to show and hide the responsive menu.

```
/* Mobile Navigation*/

$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {

    var nav = $('.js-main-nav');
    var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');
    nav.slideToggle(200);
    if(icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')){
        icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
        $(".js--main-nav").slideDown();

    }
    else {
        icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
        $(".js--main-nav").slideUp();
    }
});

var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
   if(width >= 768){
       $(".js--main-nav").slideDown();
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is working in my test env. Check adding some custom class while resize function and have a look in html through inspect element. If its adding your custom class to html then you might need some css fixes.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to add this code, and it worked fine. `window.onresize = function(){
        if (window.innerWidth > 767)
        {
            $(".js--main-nav").show();
        }
        else if (window.innerWidth <= 767)
        {
            $(".js--main-nav").hide();
        }
    }`